# Provider do not notify listeners using Provider package in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a simple heros profile app using flutter and Marvel API. For state management I'm using provider package and the bloc strategy with streams.
I created a widget that is my search bar where the user will input the hero's name, there I added a call to the CharacterProfileFormProvider queryCharacter method whenever the user click in the submit button or submit the form. In the queryCharacter method a call a service class that acess the API and return the hero.

Code for the call:

```
onFieldSubmitted: (value) async {
            if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
              await characterProfileFormProvider
                  .queryCharacter(characterNameController.text);
            }
          }
```

Code for the queryCharacter method:

```
queryCharacter(String characterName) async {
    Character character = await characterService.show(characterName);
    characterProfileProvider.changeCharacter(character);
  }
```

Code for the API call:

```
Future<Character> show(String characterName) async {
    String url = this.baseUrl + '/$resource';

    Map<String, dynamic> query = this.makeQueryParams();

    query['name'] = characterName;

    Character character;

    try {
      Response response = await Dio().get(url, queryParameters: query);

      character = Character.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.toString()));
    } catch (e) {
      character = Character(
        id: 1009368,
        name: 'Iron Man Test',
        description:
            "Wounded, captured and forced to build a weapon by his enemies, billionaire industrialist Tony Stark instead created an advanced suit of armor to save his life and escape captivity. Now with a new outlook on life, Tony uses his money and intelligence to make the world a safer, better place as Iron Man.",
        thumbnailPath:
            'http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/9/c0/527bb7b37ff55/standard_xlarge.jpg',
        comics: 2554,
        series: 623,
        stories: 3875,
        events: 31,
      );
    }

    return character;
  }
```

After the return of the API call, the result is sent to the CharacterProfileProvider in the changeCharacter method, this method input the new character in the stream and call the notifyListeners() method.

Code for the changeCharacter method:

```
changeCharacter(Character character) {
    print(character.name);
    inputCharacter.add(character);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Finaly in my screen I use the Consumer widget to get the new value render the data on the screen

Code for the screen that consumes the data:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:marvel_api/src/models/Character.dart';
import 'package:marvel_api/src/pages/CharacterProfile/CharacterProfileProvider.dart';
import 'package:marvel_api/src/components/CharacterProfileForm/CharacterProfileForm.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:marvel_api/src/components/ImageResolver/ImageResolver.dart';

class CharacterProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CharacterProfileState createState() => _CharacterProfileState();
}

class _CharacterProfileState extends State<CharacterProfile> {
  final TextStyle numberTitleStyle = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.grey[300],
    fontSize: 24.0,
  );

  final TextStyle numberValueStyle = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 19.0,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                // Search Hero
                Expanded(
                  child: CharacterProfileForm(),
                  flex: 1,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 8,
                  child: Consumer<CharacterProfileProvider>(
                      builder: (context, characterProfileProvider, widget) {
                    return StreamBuilder<Character>(
                        stream: characterProfileProvider.outputCharacter,
                        initialData: Character(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          print('Rebuild');
                          return SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  // Hero Thumbnail
                                  Container(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
                                      child: ImageResolver(
                                        image: snapshot.data.thumbnailPath,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  // Hero Info
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      // Character Name:
                                      Text(
                                        'Name:',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey[300],
                                          fontSize: 28.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        snapshot.data.name,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 22.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 7.0,
                                      ),

                                      // Character Description:
                                      Text(
                                        'Description:',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey[300],
                                          fontSize: 28.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        snapshot.data.description,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 22.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 7.0,
                                      ),

                                      // Number of comics
                                      Text(
                                        'Number of comics:',
                                        style: numberTitleStyle,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        '$snapshot.data.comics',
                                        style: numberValueStyle,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 8.0,
                                      ),

                                      // Number of series
                                      Text(
                                        'Number of series:',
                                        style: numberTitleStyle,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        '$snapshot.data.series',
                                        style: numberValueStyle,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 8.0,
                                      ),

                                      // Number of stories
                                      Text(
                                        'Number of stories:',
                                        style: numberTitleStyle,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        '$snapshot.data.stories',
                                        style: numberValueStyle,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 8.0,
                                      ),

                                      // Number of events
                                      Text(
                                        'Number of events:',
                                        style: numberTitleStyle,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        '$snapshot.data.events',
                                        style: numberValueStyle,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 8.0,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                      });
                  }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is where I put my provider declarations:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:marvel_api/src/pages/CharacterProfile/CharacterProfile.dart';
import 'package:marvel_api/src/pages/CharacterProfile/CharacterProfileProvider.dart';
import 'package:marvel_api/src/components/CharacterProfileForm/CharacterProfileFormProvider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => CharacterProfileFormProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => CharacterProfileProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: CharacterProfile(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, all providers class extends from ChangeNotifier class.

My problem is when the notifyListener method is called the listeners are not rebuilt, I confirmed this using the VS Code debugger and I tried to use Provider.of() put I got the same result. Can someone help me or show me where I was wrong.

Comment: where did you create `characterProfileFormProvider` and `characterProfileProvider`? are you sure they're the same instance `Provider.of<characterProfileFormProvider>(context, listen: false)` ?

Comment: Already tried ```Provider.of<characterProfileFormProvider>(context, listen: false)```

Comment: Also both ```characterProfileFormProvider``` and ```characterProfileProvider``` were created in the ```MultiProvider``` widget. Also, ```characterProfileFormProvider``` is used in the first code block that showed and ```characterProfileProvider``` is used via Consumer widget it's in the fifth code block.

Comment: I see you inserted them in the widget tree with MultiProvider but I can't see where did you create the variables you use in onFieldSubmitted and onFieldSubmitted, can you add the widget code where you use those methods to see how you call them

Comment: Also I would recommend to just use a regular StreamProvider instead of you want to see the changes of the stream, using a ChangeNotifier with a StreamBuilder won't update the value emitted in the stream